# A stronger form of Bezout's lemma and Smith normal form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, smith-normal-form

**Context:** I am interested in the Smith decomposition of the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & c
\end{pmatrix}~,
$$where $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$. I know that the Smith normal form is
$$
S = \begin{pmatrix}
\gcd(a,b,c) & 0\\
0 & \frac{ac}{\gcd(a,b,c)}
\end{pmatrix}~,
$$
however, I want to understand better the invertible integer matrices $U,V$ such that $S = UAV$.

As a first step, I tried to find invertible integer matrices $P$ and $Q$ such that
$$
PAQ = \begin{pmatrix}
\gcd(a,b,c) & *\\
* & *
\end{pmatrix}~.
$$
By Bezout's lemma, there are integers $x,y,z$ such that $ax+by+cz = \gcd(a,b,c)$, so I found that one possible choice of $P,Q$ is given by
$$
P_{11} Q_{11} = x~,\quad P_{11} Q_{21} = y~,\quad P_{12} Q_{21} = z~.
$$
Since $\det P = 1$ and $\det Q = 1$, we have $\gcd(P_{11},P_{12})=1$ and $\gcd(Q_{11},Q_{21})=1$. It follows that
$$
P_{11} = \gcd(x,y)~,\quad Q_{21} = \gcd(y,z) \implies y = \gcd(x,y) \gcd(y,z)~.
$$
Other components of $P,Q$ can be chosen appropriately.

**Question:** Show that, given $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$, there are always $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$ such that $ax+by+cz = \gcd(a,b,c)$ **and** $y = \gcd(x,y) \gcd(y,z)$.

This is clearly stronger than Bezout's lemma; for example, for $a=3,b=0,c=2$, the integers $x=1,y=0,z=-1$ satisfy $ax+by+cz = 1 = \gcd(a,b,c)$, but $y = 0 \ne 1 = \gcd(x,y)\gcd(y,z)$.

Of course the existence of the above Smith normal form guarantees that such $x,y,z$ do exist but I am looking for a more elementary proof.